# Charles Proxy with Android empty content problem

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I try to observe and manipulate incoming and outgoing packages with Charles during Android development.

I used Charles with many other projects but there is a problem with current one.

**This is not a certificate or ip settings error, because I can observe packages of other Android projects with same setup.**

I use same `network_secuirty_config.xml` for all.

Charles looks like this for the project:

[image: Charles view]

Comment: have you started SSL proxying ? the lock symbol is locked or unlocked for ur charles ?

Comment: @Anmol yes I have started

Comment: My doubt regarding this issue, there is a submodule in my project (internal sdk). I put secuirty config xml inside it also (and mentioned in it's manifest too) but didn't work.